# What's the type of *the* element in a Set?

Tags: java, set

I have this code:

```
for(GlCapabs_e capName : capabs.keySet()){
    x = capName.get();
}
```

where `GlCapabs_e` is an `enum` and `capabs` is an `EnumMap<GlCapabs_e, Boolean>`. But `GlCapabs_e` type up there is wrong, as I can't use `get()` on `capName;` it can't be a constant, it has to be a type to support `get()` so to return the value of the key.

I've read somewhere in Java documentation (I can't find it anymore) that a "special" type exists like `elementOf`, `itemOf` or something alike but googling them didn't return anything pertaining my matter. And above this I'm not sure whether it's this type that I'm supposed to use.

Comment: It's an `EnumMap` parameterized how?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for replying. I edited to show the EnumMap parameters

Comment: I'm confused, if it's iterating across the key set, shouldn't each value be one of the enum instances?

In other words `capabs.keySet()` should return `Set<GlCapabs_e>`, and this for loop will iterate across each enum value you have defined.

Comment: @aruisdante how then can I use `get()` to get the value?

Comment: You don't. See Sotirios's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the `keySet`. If you want to get the value mapped to each key in the key set, use the `EnumMap` to retrieve the value

```
for(GlCapabs_e capName : capabs.keySet()){
    x = capabs.get(capName);
}
```

Or iterate over the `entrySet`

```
for (Entry<GlCapabs_e, Boolean> entry : capabs.entrySet()) {
    x = entry.getValue(); // the entry holds both the key and the mapped value
}
```

Remember, [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is an implementation of [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), it therefore inherits/implements all of its methods.

Comment: Indeed, I believe the second one is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Sotirios and I thank the others too.